# Convert a column to row in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Please consider this table:

**Table1**

```
NUMBER        NAME       
----------------------
01              A              
01              B        
02              A        
01              C        
02              C
03              C
04              C
```

I want to convert it to

**Table2**

```
NAME    NUM01   NUM02   NUM03   NUM04   NUM05
--------------------------------------------------
A       01      02      NULL    NULL    NULL
B       01      NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
C       01      02      03      04      NULL
```

In **Table2**, the number of columns is fixed `(NUM01->05)`. If `NAME` value has more than **5 NUMBER** values, it just select top 5. If it has less than 5, then fill **NULL** in remain columns.

I have many different values in `NAME` column, so I can't think of an appropriate way to convert **Table1** right.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'number' values appear to be strings, and you can't have a column called `number` unless you use a quoted identifier, so I've substituted `value` to create your sample data:

```
create table table1(value varchar2(7), name varchar2(4));
insert into table1 (value, name)
select '01', 'A' from dual
union all select '01', 'B' from dual
union all select '02', 'A' from dual
union all select '01', 'C' from dual
union all select '02', 'C' from dual
union all select '03', 'C' from dual
union all select '04', 'C' from dual
/
```

You can use an analytic function to assign a row number or ranking to each value:

```
select name, value,
  row_number() over (partition by name order by value) as rn
from table1;

NAME VALUE           RN
---- ------- ----------
A    01               1
A    02               2
B    01               1
C    01               1
C    02               2
C    03               3
C    04               4
```

And then you can [`pivot` that query](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#CHDFAFIE) (as long as you're on 11g or higher) to get the result you want:

```
select *
from (
  select name, value,
    row_number() over (partition by name order by value) as rn
  from table1
)
pivot (max(value) as value for (rn) in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5));

NAME 1_VALUE 2_VALUE 3_VALUE 4_VALUE 5_VALUE
---- ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
A    01      02                             
B    01                                     
C    01      02      03      04
```

Anything ranked higher than 5 is ignored by the pivot operation.

Comment: Excellent answer! Exactly what I need, thank you very much!